# What is the effect of energy drinks on the heart?

Tags: diet, cardiology, heart

I was watching a [Youtube video of a man who supposedly drank 20 energy drinks in a row.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ANmneU5BD-U) It appears that his heart enlarged greatly. Is this something that energy drinks could actually do?

Comment: I assume my following question as related: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/20390/do-cardiologists-learn-nutrition-as-part-of-their-expertise-in-cardiology

Answer (score 1):

In short, there seems to be no evidence that acute caffeine overdose by drinking a great amount of energy drink would result in heart enlargement (hypertrophic or dilated cardiomyopathy). It could cause severe caffeine overdose, though.

8 oz (237 ml) of an energy drink can contain 150 mg of caffeine ([Mayo Clinic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/in-depth/caffeine/art-20049372)).

20 such drinks would give you 3,000 mg (3 g) of caffeine and 4.7 liters of water.

**3 g of caffeine,** does not seem to be lethal:

> Lethal doses of caffeine have been reported at blood concentrations of
>   80 to 100 micrograms/ml which can be reached with ingestion of
>   approximately 10 grams or greater. ([Stat Pearls, 2019](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK532910/))

**4.7 liters of water** drunk in a short time can result in fatal water intoxication. There is a report of a woman dying after drinking [4 liters of water in 2 hours](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/england/bradford/7779079.stm).

Symptoms of caffeine overdose: [How to recognize caffeine overdose (Nursing, 2019)](https://journals.lww.com/nursing/Fulltext/2019/04000/How_to_recognize_caffeine_overdose.15.aspx):

> Moderate toxicity can cause restlessness, tremors, anxiety, mood
>   changes, and gastrointestinal discomfort (such as vomiting). Very high
>   doses of ingested caffeine (more than 6 mg/kg) can decrease both
>   physical and cognitive performance and induce severe gastrointestinal
>   distress. Extremely high blood levels (up to 150mg/kg) of caffeine
>   can cause changes including hypokalemia, ventricular dysrhythmias,
>   hypotension, rhabdomyolysis, and death. Blood caffeine concentrations
>   around 150 mg/kg of body weight can be fatal.